# How to extract table data from webpage using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, html-table

Please note I am a beginner to PowerShell and HTML.

I am trying to extract some table data from a webpage using PowerShell. The way I do this is by using PowerShell and Selenium webdriver to automate opening a specific webpage on chrome, login and navigate to the page with the table.

The webpage is dependant on the IP address of a managed ethernet switch so unfortunately you cannot go onto the website to try this yourself. I have uploaded a section of the HTML script and a screenshot of the webpage. Hope this helps.

The problem I'm facing is that any time I try to extract the table data I get back the following issue or similar:

```
"Exception calling "FindElementByXPath" with "1" argument(s): "no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="blueLinkBold11"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.138)"
At line:11 char:1
+ $chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="blueLinkBold11"]').Text
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoSuchElementException"
```

Here is my current powershell script:

```
$Scriptpath="C:\ATE Solutions\Applications\EA-0113\HABC_Script"

Add-Type -Path "$Scriptpath\WebDriver.dll"



$chrome=New-Object "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver"

$chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.1.101/login.cgi")

$chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="password"]').SendKeys('Password1')

$chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="loginBtn"]').Click()

$chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="blueLinkBold11"]/div[2]/a/span').Click()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="tbl2"]/tbody/tr[7]/td[6]').Text
```

This image shows the table data I am trying to extract and the HTML script for it:

[image]

If you require more information or more images please let me know.

Here is a list of what I have tried so far:

1. Using the 'findelementsbyxpath'  function on the specific table element.
2. Using the 'Invoke-WebRequest' function with the following script,

$pagecontent = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri "http://192.168.1.101/index.cgi"
$TABLE = $pagecontent.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('table')

These all come back with a similar issue that it was unable to locate the element.

Comment: From my understanding the data on netgear switches is provided in JSON, I would look at the network requests in chrome and identify the requests that do the login and then the data request & response for that table. (PS. you can get the powershell equivilants of requests also from the network tab in chrome). I feel this approach would be easier than using selenium.

Comment: Why are you using Click()?  The click will route you to a different URL.

Comment: It's telling you it can't find he element specific by the search path. How did you come up with that? Perhaps you're not on the page you think you are - I suggest you do some troubelshooting and save the page locally so you can check it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments. The comment from 'Nick.McDermaid' and 'jdweng'
has helped me to solve my issue. Turns out I was searching on the wrong webpage.

Although the URL on chrome was 'http://192.168.1.101/index.cgi', If I hover over the 'Port Status' button on the webpage it shows a different URL in the bottom left corner of the page, 'http://192.168.1.101/status.cgi'. If I use this URL and a bit of tweaking to my code it works and allows me to extract the data I need.

Here is my current working script,

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\ATE Solutions\Applications\EA-0113\HABC_Script\WebDriver.dll"
$chrome=New-Object "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver"
$chrome.Manage().Window.Minimize()
$chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.1.101/login.cgi")
$chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="password"]').SendKeys('Password1')
$chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="loginBtn"]').Click()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.1.101/status.cgi")
$chrome.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="tbl2"]/tbody').Text
$chrome.Close()
$chrome.Quit()
```

I use Labview and Teststand to automate running this script using the powershell.exe and organise the extracted table data below.

```
"Port Port Description Port Status Speed Linked Speed Flow Control Max MTU

    Auto
    Disable
    10M Half
    10M Full
    100M Half
    100M Full


    Enable
    Disable
    1 Up Auto 1000M Disable 16349
2 Down Auto No Speed Disable 16349
3 Down Auto No Speed Disable 16349
4 Down Auto No Speed Enable 16349
5 Down Auto No Speed Disable 16349"
```